# attribute lookup s3.ServiceResource on boto3.resources.factory failed

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to try my model. The data is saved in AWS. I use boto3 simply like

```
        self.s3_img = S3Images(boto3.resource('s3'))
        self.s3_obj = S3GetObjects()
```

I met this error when I feed the data and model in to the pytorch training pipeline.

The code looks like

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pytorch_lightning import Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
        checkpoint_callback=checkpoint_callback,
        callbacks=get_callbacks(chkpt_path),
        fast_dev_run=False,
        max_epochs=100,
        resume_from_checkpoint=checkpoint_path
    )
trainer.fit(model)
```

The error is

```
  File "main.py", line 191, in <module>
    train()
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydra/main.py", line 20, in decorated_main
    run_hydra(
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydra/_internal/utils.py", line 171, in run_hydra
    hydra.run(
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydra/_internal/hydra.py", line 82, in run
    return run_job(
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hydra/plugins/common/utils.py", line 109, in run_job
    ret.return_value = task_function(task_cfg)
  File "main.py", line 176, in train
    trainer.fit(model)
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/states.py", line 48, in wrapped_fn
    result = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1084, in fit
    results = self.accelerator_backend.train(model)
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/cpu_backend.py", line 39, in train
    results = self.trainer.run_pretrain_routine(model)
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1224, in run_pretrain_routine
    self._run_sanity_check(ref_model, model)
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1257, in _run_sanity_check
    eval_results = self._evaluate(model, self.val_dataloaders, max_batches, False)
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/evaluation_loop.py", line 305, in _evaluate
    for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(dataloader):
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 352, in __iter__
    return self._get_iterator()
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 294, in _get_iterator
    return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 801, in __init__
    w.start()
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 284, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 47, in _launch
    reduction.dump(process_obj, fp)
  File "/Users/admin/opt/anaconda3/envs/kk/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'boto3.resources.factory.s3.ServiceResource'>: attribute lookup s3.ServiceResource on boto3.resources.factory failed
```

Can anyone tell me what's the meaning of this error and how to solve it? Thanks for any suggestions and help!

Comment: The code you posted doesn't match your exception. Your exception is triggered by some call to `train()`, which ins't present in your posted code.

Comment: You also don't show how your passing your data read from S3